# Getting multiple errors for css selectors?

Tags: css, syntax-error

This kind of just popped up out of nowhere after messing with the HTML. Not sure what happened or what could have caused it, feel like ive checked everything.
[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIBIL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget for add semicolon at width: 8em

[image]

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can check my answer for assign your question is solved.